# In the London 2012 Olympic Football, what players will receive medals?

Tags: football, olympics, awards

When the football teams that finish in the medal ranking positions (winners, runners up, and 3rd place playoff winners) are awarded the medals, which players will receive medals?

Will it be all squad members regardless of if they played? Or is there a minimum numbers of minutes a player must have spent on the pitch?

I am curious, because if it is the latter I wonder if managers would feel pressured to play each player the minimum minutes in the event they reach a medal position. This would then potentially reduce the chances of the teams playing at their best.

Comment: @Sancho: Well I do play football (not at an Olympic level mind) and there are people who do play football at an Olympic level. So arguable this question is valid? What do you think?

Comment: @Sancho You're linking to a question which disagrees with the FAQ. The irony...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each of the players of the three top-ranked teams who feature on the 
official team lists shall receive a medal.

it's taken from [Regulations of the Olympic Football Tournaments London 2012](http://www.fifa.com/mm/document/tournament/competition/01/33/73/30/regulationsoft2012_update10.15.10_e.pdf) - By FIFA
Chapter XI, Page 53, Article 41 - Olympic medals and diplomas

[image: Olympic medals and diplomas]